# Read the form field type after the submit?

Tags: php, forms, input, hidden-field

Using PHP, after a form has been submitted via "POST"...

I am trying to detect if an input type is HIDDEN.

FYI:  Each hidden input has a different NAME and different ID.

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="uniqueID1" name="SomeName1" value="99" />
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The field type isn't sent through with the data, so you can't do that.

Comment: So better you can use the name or ID

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There may be a better solution.

Comment: After the form is submitted the only information you will get is field name and value as a key pair so you will have no information in regards weather it was a hidden field or whatever type it was.

Comment: Use AJAX. After submit you can get hidden input via jquery.attr('') and send variables to a php function.

Comment: While you are submitting your form, first create one javascript function to check your input type, then go for the further.

Comment: train_fox...  You're right.  AJAX might be the solution.  I'll be testing this method.  If this works, I'll post my solution. Back soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only resolution that I found for this...

I created a jQuery function that would 'find' all HIDDEN fields prior to the form submitting the data.  It would then create additional [new] HIDDEN fields with the input naming structure:  name="hidden1" value="1" ,  name="hidden2" value="1" , etc.  using a FOR loop.  In my PHP processing code, it would 'see' all input values that begin with "hidden" as the field name and then do ... whatever with these hidden fields.

The bottom line...
There is no way to have PHP detect file types of the input fields of a form **that is processing to another PHP page.

**FOOTNOTE:  It may be possible to do this if a PHP page is submitting to itself!  (I don't know.  I didn't test this.)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

Assign your all fields array names.

```
<input type="hidden" id="uniqueID1" name="hidden[SomeName1]" value="99" />
```

After form submit, in PHP.

```
<?php
if (! empty($_POST)) {
  foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
   if ($k == 'hidden') { // Here you get if the field is hidden one.
    if (! empty($v)) {
     foreach ($_POST as $hidName => $hidValue) {
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I cannot change the field names.  They are generated by a 3rd party Lead Generating "form creator" site.  My code must follow the example as detailed in my question.  Is there any way to detect input type via PHP?  That really is the bottom line.